# How can i deploy same docker image on ECS with different public url

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

We have a docker image say Tomcat which will run on port 8080. Now we need run the same docker image for different customers and need to give them  public url for their individual instances (each customer will have their different urls).Can anyone suggest how to achieve this  using AWS ECS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place an application load balancer in front of ECS and perform host based routing. This allows each customers to have their own URL and run multiple customer containers on same ECS cluster. Also ECS integrates well with application load balancer.

Some useful links:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-alb-auto-register/
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/